# В чем разница между collection.OrderedDict и обычным словарем в версии 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`OrderedDict` модуля `collection` отслеживает порядок добавления в словарь пар «ключ - значение». Зачем? Обычный словарь делает тоже самое.

```
avto ={}
avto['alex'] = 'bmw'
avto['masha'] = 'vaz'
avto['jens'] = 'toyota'
avto['jonh'] = 'volga'
print(avto)
for name, avt in avto.items():
    print(name.title() + "'s " +
    avt.title() + ".")
```

Comment: Думаю, в обычном словаре порядок не гарантирован

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Но по факту получается,что простой словарь добавляет строго в том порядке,который был задан.

Comment: По факту не то, чтобы _получается_, а скорее _получилось на этих данных, на этой системе и на этой реализации/версии языка_.

Comment: Хуже того: если я не ошибаюсь, то две последовательные итерации не гарантируют одинаковый порядок тоже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В одной из последних версий интерпретатора была обновлена внутренняя механика работы словаря. Это делалось для уменьшения занимаемой словарём памяти, но одним из побочных эффектов стало сохранение порядка.

Однако, нужно понимать, что это всего лишь побочный эффект, который присутствует только в некоторых версиях конкретного интерпретатора.

Если вы напишете программу, которая подразумевает, что словарь должен сохранять свой порядок, то она не будет работать корректно на старых версиях интерпретатора, или на других интерпретаторах, а возможно даже в каких-то будущих версиях интерпретатора.

Поэтому если для вашей программы важно, чтобы словарь сохранял порядок, рекомендуется использовать OrderedDict - он гарантирует сохранение порядка  и на других интерпретаторах.

Comment: Больше подробностей по этому вопросу: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 1):

Из справки: [словарь - **неупорядоченный** набор пар ключ: значение, с требованием, чтобы ключи были уникальными.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)